# Bind only value from KeyValuePair to GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, keyvaluepair

In ASPX File

```
   <asp:GridView ID="gvSavedAddresses" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="AddressType" ItemStyle-Width="9%" HeaderText="Type"
     HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAddressType" Text='<%#Eval("AddressType")%>'> 
    </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

In CS File

```
objAddr.AddressType = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(dr["AddressTypeLookupID"].ToString(), dr["AddressType"].ToString());
```

I want to display only Value in the grid. But in my code it is showing both key and value in grid cell. how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the field to its actual type, and retrieve `Value`:

```
<%# ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)Eval("AddressType")).Value %>
```

Comment: @RaghavendraDevraj, just tried to reproduce it locally - worked fine. Maybe the exception it thrown for other records? If other records have `AddressType = null`, then additional checks should be applied.